# How to change the background of a table row?

Tags: jquery, html, css

My HTML code:

```
<table class="tableclass">
<th>id</th><th>Name</th><th>Value</th>
<tr>
    <td>001</td>
    <td>Name 001</td>
    <td>This is some value for Key 001</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>002</td>
    <td>Name 002</td>
    <td>This is some value for Key 002</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>003</td>
    <td>Name 003</td>
    <td>This is some value for Key 003</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>004</td>
    <td>Name 004</td>
    <td>This is some value for Key 004</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

I'm able to show alternate colors with CSS:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #CCD1D1;
}
```

And My jQuery to highlight clicked table row :

```
$(".tableclass tr").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("rowHighlight");
});
```

The class `.rowHighlight{background-color:#AEB6BF;}`

With this code Im not able to change the background color of the odd numbered row that has the background from css. I want to be able to change the background of that rows too.

How do I do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Add the background color to td instead of tr so, .rowHighlight td {background-color:#AEB6BF;}

Comment: Thanks Heaps .. It worked!!!!

Comment: updated with border issue you can adjust it as per your need

Comment: `tr.rowHighlight{}` little better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use .rowHighlight td{background-color:your color;

```js
$(".tableclass tr").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("rowHighlight");
});
```

```css
table {
border:0px solid #CCC;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
td {
    border:none;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #CCD1D1;
}




.rowHighlight td{background-color:red; padding:0px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tableclass">
<th>id</th><th>Name</th><th>Value</th>
<tr>
    <td>001</td>
    <td>Name 001</td>
    <td>This is some value for Key 001</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>002</td>
    <td>Name 002</td>
    <td>This is some value for Key 002</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>003</td>
    <td>Name 003</td>
    <td>This is some value for Key 003</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>004</td>
    <td>Name 004</td>
    <td>This is some value for Key 004</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: How do I Remove the border/white space that is appearing by default? 
I tried `<table border="0">` but its not working. I want the entire row to appear in the horizontal line without any white spaces between `<td>`

Comment: How do I Remove the border/white space that is appearing by default? 
I tried `<table border="0">` but its not working. I want the entire row to appear in the horizontal line without any white spaces between `<td>`

Comment: @Somename Updated it. You can adjust the outer border as per your need. Also see at padding that I have added in last class. you can remove it if you don't want

Comment: Can you add "**Why** td is required?" Why not selector with higher selectivity?

Comment: @vp_arth but this selector does not change the color when clicked if its an  odd row. It retains its background color.

Comment: it's change. `tr.rowHighlight` is not just `.rowHighlight`. First is some stronger.

Answer (score 1):

In the jQuery, do this instead

```
$(".tableclass tr").click(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color","#AEB6BF")
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<table class="tableclass">
<th>id</th><th>Name</th><th>Value</th>
<tr>
    <td>001</td>
    <td>Name 001</td>
    <td>This is some value for Key 001</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>002</td>
    <td>Name 002</td>
    <td>This is some value for Key 002</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>003</td>
    <td>Name 003</td>
    <td>This is some value for Key 003</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>004</td>
    <td>Name 004</td>
    <td>This is some value for Key 004</td>
</tr>

</table>

**If you want to change the row color on hover or on click, you can do this using css.** 

.tableclass tr:hover, .tableclass tr:active, .tableclass tr:visited{
background-color: #CCD1D1;
cursor:pointer;

}
```